# Why is this jQuery.animate() function not changing the visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in my website I want a div (which contains an image) to appear some time after the page is loaded. I initially set its visibility to hidden, and in my javascript document, my website waits for a second and then animates its visibility back to 'visible.'

But if I open the page, the image wouldn't show at all. When it was a simple visibility change (Without animate function), the image popped up properly. What could be wrong with my implementation?

```
<div id="scroll" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5%; left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%); visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="images/insta.png" style="width: 10%;
    height: 10%; display: block; margin: auto;">
</div>
```

js (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#scroll").animate({ visibility: "visible" }, "slow");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: From documentation: _All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; **most properties** that are **non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality** (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.animate` does not show hidden elements and it does not work on elements with `visibility: hidden;"

From the documentation

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and
>   .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible
>   as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement"
>   ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but
>   the element will remain hidden.

The solution, if you need to use `visibility: hidden;` is to set the image's `opacity` to `0`, then animate the opacity to `1` while at the same time set the `visibility` to `visible`.

```
$("#scroll").css({ visibility: 'visible' }).animate({
      opacity: 1,
});
```